# Specify a vaild path to the correct hive jars using $HIVE_METASTORE_JARS or change spark.sql.hive.metastore.version to 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, metastore

When i try to run spark-submit on the Jar which had HiveContext,getting the below error.

**Spark-defaults.conf had**

```
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 0.14.0
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars ----/external_jars/hive-metastore-0.14.0.jar
#spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars maven
```

I would like to use Hive Metastore version 0.14. both spark and hadoop are on diff clusters.

Can anyone helping me with resolving this one?

16/09/19 16:52:24 INFO HiveContext: default warehouse location is /apps/hive/warehouse
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Builtin jars can only be used when hive execution version == hive metastore version. Execution: 1.2.1 != Metastore: 0.14.0.
 Specify a vaild path to the correct hive jars using $HIVE_METASTORE_JARS or change spark.sql.hive.metastore.version to 1.2.1.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:271)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$cla

Answer (score 0):

try

```
val hadoopConfig: Configuration = spark.hadoopConfiguration 
hadoopConfig.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem].getNam‌​e) 
hadoopConfig.set("fs.file.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getName)
```

in the spark

Comment: Thank you tesnik03.Coul you please give me code in Java.

Comment: Added this code to Spark application. but it didnt help. Can you provide me any other recommendation. Am i doing it right? SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark POC tar Application"); // conf.setMaster("spark://*****.net:7077"‌​); conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName()‌​); conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());

Comment: I think you need to build spark with specific hive libraries. Please consult Spark documentation for build from source. Curious: Any specific reason to use older versions of Hive